# How can I reinitialize an array in a method and have the new size update in main?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

My teacher gave our AP Computer Science class one of the free response questions from our upcoming test. The question says:

> Write a method `public static void insert(int[] a, int n, int x)` that inserts `x` in order among the first `n` elements of `a`, assuming  these elements are arranged in ascending order.

So practically, she wants us to send of an array of x values and get an array back with x + 1 values. Is that even possible while using a void function? Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Console output:
 * 
 * Array 'a' in insert method after inserting x: [4, 6, 7, 8]
 * Array 'a' in main method after insert has been called: [4, 6, 7]
 */

package chapter14Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Chapter14Test
{
    public static void insert(int[] a, int n, int x)
    {
        //declare variables
        List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer[] tempA = new Integer[a.length + 1];

        //traverse a and add values to aList
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            //add a value to aList
            aList.add(a[i]);
        } //end for

        //traverse aList until n + 1 is reached
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            //determine if aList value is greater than x
            if (aList.get(i).intValue() >= x)
            {
                //add x at index i
                aList.add(i, x);

                //exit loop
                i = n + 1;
            } //end if
        } //end if

        //determine if x needs to be added at the end
        if (x > aList.get(aList.size() - 1).intValue())
        {
            //add x to end of aList
            aList.add(x);
        } //end if

        //convert aList to an array
        tempA = aList.toArray(new Integer[0]);

        //reinitialize a
        a = new int[tempA.length];

        //transfer tempA values to a
        for (int i = 0; i < tempA.length; i++)
        {
            //transfer value at tempA element to a element
            a[i] = tempA[i].intValue();
        } //end for

        //display a
        System.out.println("Array 'a' in insert method after inserting x: " + Arrays.toString(a));
    } //insert

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //declare array
        int[] a = new int[] {4, 6, 7};

        //insert 8 among the first two elements in a
        insert(a, 2, 5);

        //display a
        System.out.println("Array 'a' in main method after insert has been called: " + Arrays.toString(a));
    } //main
}
```

Comment: is it possible ... if you save it in a class variable, yes. but remember, you can't "enlarge" an array, you'll have to create a new one.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much! She just said to assume that the array parameter given was not full.

Comment: @LoganKulinski *"She just said to assume that the array parameter given was not full."* Then you shouldn't create a new array, just "shift" the existing items from a certain index to `index + 1`.

Comment: @Tom Yes. She said that after I brought up the issue of resizing. I am modifying my code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. So when you write the below statement you pass the address or reference of `a` and hence whatever changes your `insert` method will make will eventually be reflected back in the array `a` of your `main` method.

```
insert(a, 2, 5);
```

Insert method will modify `a`. You don't have to return it back. The changes will be reflected in your `main` method.

**Note:** It won't happen if `a` has to be enlarged to store the new values.

Comment: Now what about when I put "a = new int[tempA.length];"? That change does not seem to be reflected back in main.

Comment: Yes. That is the problem I ran into.

Comment: @Kevin I agree, but the OP confirms in above comment that he won't be enlarging it.

Comment: @user2004685 oh, didn´t see that one yet.

Comment: Yeah. I brought up this issue with my teacher and she said to assume that the array would not be fully filled. I was just curious that if it was filled, how I could resize it in a method and reflect that change in main.